# Why are there different voicings in this example?

Tags: chord-progressions

[image: C minor and major examples of VII7-VI6-VII7-V65-I]

The image above (from Korean composer Byung Dong Paik's *Theory of Harmonics*, page 127) shows progressions diminished and half-diminished 7th chords

What I'm curious about here is that the positions of the notes in minor (diminished) at the top of the image and major (half diminished) at the bottom of the image are different.

From left to right, chords in C minor start with B-D-F-A, whereas in C major they start with B-A-F-D.

But why different positions? If you swap the chords that start in C minor and the ones that start in C major, will there be any problems with the progression?

Or is it just a change to show that you can do a lot of different things? The book doesn't explain much about this.

So, if you know something I don't know, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voicings are different simply to show a variety of possibilities in how the chords in this progression can be written. There is no other significance. The voicing for the C minor progression could have been used for the C major version, and vice versa.